# how can i handle the recursion in this class function?

Tags: c++, function, class, recursion, stringstream

i have a class with a member function that i have called -> internal_connections(stringstream)
i'll show you a brief portion of the code.

```
      while(ss>>str){
            ss1<<ss.str();
            ss.str("");
            ss<<" ASSIGN ";
            ss<<" "<<ran_str<<" "; 
            ss<<" = ";
            ss<<ss1.str();
            internal_connections(ss);
```

if i build the project i got an error which says: use of deleted function std::basic_stringsteam(......
can you help me?

Comment: From the code shown it is pretty clear that this is c++ code. However you forgot to tag the question with c++, which is probably why it went so long without an answer.

Comment: you are right, i'm new here.

Comment: Where is the recursion you write about? What are the types involved? Too many question. As a rule, you need to extract and provide a [mcve] from your code. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is not very clear. You are showing neither the full error message nor the full signature of internal_connections.

However the bits of information you have given us point to a problem of passing the stream to internal_connections by value. You can not do that because streams are not copyable. The usual solution to this problem is to pass the stream by reference instead.

Answer (score 0):

Read about it [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/stringstream/). You will see #3.

> (3) copy constructor (deleted)
>   Deleted (no copy constructor).

Maybe change internal_connections constructor to accept a string and use internal_connections(ss.str())